# Use PHP class in AJAX call without extra handlers

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

At the moment I use two `php` files for my `AJAX` requests. One file holds the functions, the other file contains a `switch` function that determines which funtion should be fired. This works fine but recently I looked into a project that used `php` classes. The most interesting part I found was the fact that within the `ajax` calls, the url was set directly to the class and function.

The code is as follow:

```
class Score extends CI_Controller {
 const INDIVIDUAL_SCORE_RANGE_SIZE = 7;

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('benchmarkscore','',TRUE);
   $this->load->model('aiinst','',TRUE);

   $this->load->helper('score');   
   $this->load->helper('info'); 
 }

 function index()
 {
    show_404('score', false);
 }

 function accountingratio() {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

        $ratio = strtolower($this->input->post('ratio'));
        $filter = strtolower($this->input->post('filter'));

        if(in_array($ratio, array('roi', 'rr', 'qr', 'cr', 'sr', 'vr'))) {
            $ai_inst = $this->aiinst->findById($session_data['ICIOM1ID']);  

            $myScore = $this->benchmarkscore->getMyScoreByAccountingRatio($ratio, $session_data['ICIOM1ID']);   
            $avgScore = $this->benchmarkscore->getAverageScoreOfOthersByAccountingRatio($ratio, $session_data['ICIOM1ID'], $filter, $ai_inst);
            $allScores = $this->benchmarkscore->getAllScoresByAccountingRatio($ratio, $session_data['ICIOM1ID'], $filter, $ai_inst);

            // We should only show 20 scores so we have to filter
            // some data.   
            $filterDescription = getFilterDescription(count($allScores), $filter, $ai_inst);

            $filteredScores = filterRelatedScores($allScores, $ai_inst['ICIOM1ID'], Score::INDIVIDUAL_SCORE_RANGE_SIZE);

            $deviation = getBenchmarkDeviation($myScore['myscore'], $avgScore['avgscore']);
            $deviation = $deviation == -1 ? 'N/A' : $deviation.'%';

            $result = createResultArray($myScore['myscore'], $avgScore['avgscore'], $filteredScores,            
                "Uw score: ".number_format($myScore['myscore'], 2, ',', '.')."\nBenchmark afwijking: ".$deviation,
                wrapText("Benchmark score: ".number_format($avgScore['avgscore'], 2, ',', '.')."\n\n" .
                "test".$filterDescription,35),
                $filterDescription);    

            $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
            $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));
        }       
    }       
 } 
}
```

The `ajax` call:

```
function getAccountingRatioData(type, filter, callback) {
    showLoader();

    setTimeout(function() {
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/score/accountingratio',
            data: {
                ratio: type,
                filter: filter
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data) { 
            hideLoader();
            if(data == null) {
                bootbox.alert("error"); 
            } else {
                setTopChartDataProvider(data.benchmark);
                setBottomChartDataProvider(data.allscores, "test");
                setFilterInfo(data);
            }               
            if(callback)
                callback.call();
        })
        .fail(function() { hideLoader();bootbox.alert("error"); });
    }, 500); 
}
```

I was wondering how this is working because I learned that classes it self don't actually do anything, they just hold things and you should alwas create an object in order to "fire" the class..

Any thoughts?

Comment: Open any framework (Codeigniter, Kohana, Laravel) and see how it works.

Comment: You're right, there's nothing by default that maps a URL request structure to a class and method. That's what the framework does, and it's a fundamental part of its methodology. CodeIgniter, to take an example, interprets most URLs in the format `/segment1/segment2` to point to a class (segment1) and method (segment2). In short, it's a feature of the framework - nothing native.